# Jenkins Build Error Missing: cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0

Tags: maven, jdbc, jenkins

I am trying to build maven project using Jenkins.
bellow is my maven configuration in Jenkins 
[image: mavenConfiguration in jenkins]
every thing looks fine to me but I am getting the bellow error

```html
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0
   
----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.varun:myproject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

I can see the error is saying that maven is not able to resolve

`cn.guoyukun.jdbc:oracle-ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0` jar file.
but in lib folder of my project I have kept above jar.

I tried multiple solution but dint work.

In Jenkins/job/maven i kept the jar. but this dint work also.

from some jenkins Google group I found some solution but not bale to fix it.

The solution

```html
Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

 Then, install it using the command: 
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=cn.guoyukun.jdbc -DartifactId=oracle-  ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

 Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=cn.guoyukun.jdbc -DartifactId=oracle-    ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
```

The above solution looks ok to me.
as mentioned in first solution I have that jar file and I am trying to install that jar. but I am getting command not found.

I dont know how to achieve the above solution. sorry for being dumb, I am totally new to Jenkins and maven.

can any body help me to achieve the above solution or any other solution is there.

Comment: After installing the jdbc jar using mvn install, did you add the dependency in pom.xml? Can you paste the logs for installation? You can also use the goal as described in maven-install-plugin to install the jar locally. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

Comment: @deveshase I could not install ojdbc jar using maven. Bcz i have not install maven my system. In jenkins configuration I have specified maven install automatically. do I need to install maven in my system?

Comment: ok so maven will be installed automatically through Jenkins build however you still need to register your custom jar locally and add the dependencies accordingly in pom xml.